# Vue ignore parsing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Some web components has "bad" behaviour - theyre add `script` tags near to difinition. For example - a service has some html widget, for example:

```
<a href="someremote/service/url.com">some inner code</a>
```

and this widget will try to add <script tag for his own purposes, so it should looks like that:

```
<a href="someremote/service/url.com">some inner code</a>
<script src="externalurl/withjs.com"></script>
```

And when Vue see that, he tell me alot of bad words:

```
Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they... blah, blah...
```

But the client needs this, lets call it widget, in his webpage.
How can I tell my Vue - please, dont parse this scope?
Vue already have ignorance [for custom elems](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements), but this is not enough.
So, when I tried to:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
    'dont-parse-me',
]
```

// ....

```
<dont-parse-me>
   <a href="someremote/service/url.com">some inner code</a>
</dont-parse-me>
```

And I still getting same error.

How can I tell my Vue to not parse some scope?

Comment: '<a href="someremote/service/url.com" v-html>some inner code</a>'

Comment: No, this wont work, coz it not resolve <script tags inside of the element

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre

Comment: yep, this also not working

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5360